# Get the text content from a locator (Playwright and Crawlee) and default to an specific value if that locator is not found

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright, crawlee

I'm trying to develop a little crawling/scraping project with Crawlee and Playwright on JavaScript/TypeScript, For each URL I feed the crawler it tries to scrap some data like this:

```js
productDescriptionContainer = await page.locator(
      'div[class="product-details__product-description"]'
    ),
    region = await productDescriptionContainer
      .locator("p")
      .filter({ hasText: "Región:" })
      .textContent(),
    farm = await productDescriptionContainer
      .locator("p")
      .filter({ hasText: "Finca:" })
      .textContent(),
```

The problem comes when one of the locator is not found on the page. The crawler retries 3 times and completely stops the scraping process for that specific URL. I would like to set those variables to some default value if the locator is not found and continue with the next.

I hope you can shed some light onto this because I've run out of ideas (catching the error, using ||, initialise the variables...). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I found to this.

Include a .catch in the await call, to avoid throw an error, so the code continues.

On your sample, it should be like this

```
region = await productDescriptionContainer
  .locator("p")
  .filter({ hasText: "Región:" })
  .textContent(),
  .catch((e) => console.log(e))
farm = await productDescriptionContainer
  .locator("p")
  .filter({ hasText: "Finca:" })
  .textContent(),
  .catch((e) => console.log(e))
```